# Cannot test an async method that is expected to throw

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, mocha.js

I have a test case which looks like this:

```js
it("should throw when the template file does not exist", async (): Promise<void> => {
    await expect(new UpdateReadmeCommandlet().invoke()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);
});
```

And the corresponding `invoke` method is the following:

```js
public async invoke(): Promise<void> {
    fs.readFile(this.templatePath, (outerError: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer): void => {
        if (outerError !== null) {
            throw new Error(`FileNotFoundException: Cannot find file \`${this.templatePath}'.`);
        }
    });
}
```

This test is setup so that this error is thrown. When running `mocha` I am getting some really awkward error messages and everything is all over place which is most likely due to the async calls. The error message I get is `AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected with 'Error' but it was fulfilled with undefined`.

My test is written based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45496509/796036). Surprisingly enough, when I copy the `fails` method it works as described in the post. Exchanging the `throw` directive with my call to `invoke` causes the issues. So I assume I my `invoke` method has to work differently.

I still cannot figure out what is actually wrong and how I can rewrite my test s.t. doesn't interfere with other tests and that checks my assertion correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A throw in the callback passed to `fs.readFile` *will not* reject the promise returned by `public async invoke(): Promise<void> {`

## Fix

Wrap `fs.readFile` to be *async aware* and use that the cascade the promise rejection.

```
public async invoke(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((res, rej) => {
    fs.readFile(this.templatePath, (outerError: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer): void => {
        if (outerError !== null) {
            rej(new Error(`FileNotFoundException: Cannot find file \`${this.templatePath}'.`));
        }
    });

    })
}
```

Comment: Even better would be `require('util').promisify(fs.readFile)` so that you don't even have to write it using the callback-style API.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Would you mind quickly showing a snippet what your alternative would look like?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic I'm not sure how it would look in TypeScript, but in JavaScript (Node.js) you'd do something like ``const readFile = require('util').promisify(fs.readFile); ... async invoke () { return readFile(this.templatePath).then(data => data, outerError => { throw new Error(`FileNotFoundException: cannot find file \`${this.templatePath}'.`); }); }``