# I am getting an error is 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression inside an it block

Tags: javascript, chai

I am getting a failed result in test cases which is caused by an await keyword not taking effect.
The warning i am getting is `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)`
and the code for that function which uses chai library is

```
describe("Add Task", function() {
    it("Should emit AddTask Event", async () => {
        let task = {
            'taskText':"New task",
            'isDeleted': false,
        };
        await expect(taskContract.addTask(task.taskText, task.isDeleted)
            .to.emit(taskContract,"AddTask")
            .withArgs(owner.address,total_tasks));
        
    });
});`
```

I tried making the async function a normal function without arrow but it does'nt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466040/verify-that-an-exception-is-thrown-using-mocha-chai-and-async-await

Answer (score 0):

That's because `expect` doesn't return a promise, but only promises can be awaited

Remove `await` and `async`

Comment: after removing allso i am getting the error :- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')

Comment: @1181_RahulGuha `to` is a property of the return value of `expect`, not of `taskContract.addTask`. Your `)` is misplaced.

Comment: Actually, any value can be awaited. It's one of the neat things about `async`/`await`. It's the `async`/`await` equivalent of wrapping something in `Promise.resolve` to normalize it to a Promise so that you can always call `.then` on it. But, as `expect` _never_ returns a Promise, the `await` is pointless in this case, which is why you are getting a warning.